# Unity - How to capture an EventSystem UI input event from c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am not really sure if this is possible at all since I couldn't find a way to do it.
I would like to capture the input events the EventSystem object sends to the canvas to interact with the different intractable objects in there.

The Standalone Input Module I am using is not the Unity one, instead I am using Rewired's Standalone Input Module (from the asset store).

In my case I've created my own UI system and I would like to use the input that the EventSystem provides.

EDIT: I am not looking for an event sent to a particular UI_Button or other UI elements. What I want to capture is the input events themselves (i.e. when the horizontal or vertical axis has changed).

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: If you're creating your own UI system, why do you want to capture EventSystem on Unity's UI objects? Doesn't really make sense...

Comment: Because I want to avoid dealing with the algorithm of navigation input (i,e. hold a direction to advance every x seconds (but having an extra pause on the first time)). Rewired does that which I would like to keep and then just decide what to do when a particular direction has been pressed (maybe I want to play an event where the camera focuses on a 3D object and then change the texture of that object to indicate it is selected).